# List all of the element types in geodatabase

Tags: arcpy

I have been working on this project, and so far I have completed the following tasks

1. Create a new script with a hard-coded geodatabase filename, that lists the feature classes it contains to the console.
2. Create a tool in ArcGIS Pro, connected to the script, that takes parameters from users (initially, the geodatabase filename) and shows the report on the screen.
3. Give users the option for showing the report on the screen or creating a text file.

The following code is what I got so far.

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
createTextFile = arcpy.GetParameter(1)

if createTextFile:
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in featureclasses:
txtFile = open("c:\\temp\\GPMessages.txt","w")
txtFile.write (fc)
txtFile.close()

else:
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in featureclasses:    
    arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
```

For my next step, I am trying to add a code that lists all of the element types in the geodatabase, such as feature datasets, networks, rasters, domains, non-spatial tables, etc.

I think I can use ListDatasets function to list all feature datasets, but what function do I need for the rest (networks, rasters, domains, non-spatial tables)?

Comment: Have you looked at what other List functions are available?  Please try to present only a [snippet of code](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that illustrates where you are stuck rather than your whole code.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  I think you'll get an indentation error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry that I keep posting my whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @PolyGeo mention in the comments you have several list functions to retrieve different data ([ArcPy Docs -Create lists of data](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/listing-data.htm) ). You will probably use a couple of them to accomplish what you want.

Also, take a look at `ListFeatureClasses` specification, you can indicate the type of feature you want to retrieve using `feature_type` parameter ([ArcPy Docs - List Feature Classes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm)).

One last thing, you are overwriting the file in each iteration. You probably want to initiate the file with 'w' and then use 'a' to append ([Python Docs - Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)).

Comment: Thank you. I am trying the ListFeatureClasses function. I do not see anything outputted, but I think it is because my workspace does not contain any of the types I specified.

Comment: Remember that this functions return a list, in that way you can obtain the length of the list using `len(featureClasses)`.

Comment: I remember learning that function, but what is the purpose of obtaining the length of the list here?

Comment: Just to count the amount of feature classes retrieve, that's all.